# Running a few commands from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, process

I thought that this should be straightforward, but the result is puzzling me.

When I run a bash script using the command,

```
sudo ./restartccpd.bash
```

nothing appears on the screen. Also issue of

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

independently from screen after running the script produces empty, rather than showing the pid's of the daemon. This evidences that only the pkill command is working.

The contents of the script is,

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo pkill -9 ccpd
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

The commands work fine when run from a terminal. But when run as a script, as pointed out above, it is not working as expected.

I tried inserting sleep command between commands, without any avail. Also, nothing appears in syslog. So, I can not diagnose the problem.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: are you saying that *after* the script fails, if you type those commands, it works?

Comment: What I am saying is the three commands, when run individually from a terminal, work. No matter before or after running the script. The script does not work under any condition.

Comment: does it work if you don't have `sudo` in your script?

Comment: No, I already tried the script without any sudo inside. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Removing the first `#!/bin/bash` line solved the problem. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pkill` will kill anything contained `ccpd` in the command name.  Your script is called `restartccpd.bash`.  The very first line is:

```
pkill ccpd
```

So the script starts, runs `pkill` (which produces no output) and promptly kills itself.  Ta da!

The easiest solution is to rename the script.  You could also do something like:

```
kill $(pgrep -l ccpd | grep -v restartccpd | awk '{print $1}')
```

This produces a list of proccess names and pids matching `ccpd`, then removes `restartccpd` from the list, and then kills the processes with `kill`.

Comment: The `grep | awk` anti-idiom can usefully be rewritten as `awk '!/restartccpd/{print $1}'`

Comment: @larsks Your solution worked, perfectly. Any idea why it also works when the bin/bash line is removed? See my comment above.

Comment: Correct diagnosis, but not a good fix. Your proposal will kill any other process whose name contains `ccpd`. `pkill` has the `-x` option just for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As [larsks correctly diagnosed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11915064), `pkill ccpd` kills all processes whose name contains `ccpd`. Including your script.

The immediate fix is to pass the `-x` option to `pkill`, so that it only matches processes whose name is exactly `ccpd`.

Note that if your script contains `sudo` commands, it doesn't need to be invoked with `sudo`. Alternatively, you can remove all the `sudo` calls from your script, and call it with `sudo`.

You should not run this script, however. You should normally call the init script to shut down a service: `/etc/init.d/ccpd stop`. In addition to killing the daemon, this may perform other necessary clean up such as removing temporary files and locks. The only case when you should use `kill -9` is if something goes seriously wrong, causing `/etc/init.d/ccpd stop` to fail, and in that case you should do the necessary clean up manually before restarting the daemon.

The proper way to do what you're trying to do is

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd restart
```

(assuming your distribution uses the traditional SysVinit — if it uses upstart, you should run `sudo service ccpd restart` instead).

Comment: I definitely understand that I will not want to restart a daemon in this manner and rather it will be an unpardonable sin to do it this way. However, we are talking about a particular situation where the daemon has its own problems. If you want to know the situation, you will want to visit this site (http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/) or particularly this comment (http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/#comment-578224454).

Comment: @MMA I've only skimmed the thread, but I think the right thing to do here would be to fix `/etc/init.d/ccpd`. As a last resort, use `pkill -x`. Have you tried asking how to make this printer work on [ubuntu.se]?